# Effect of date type precision on performance

Tags: c++, date

At the c++ time libraries([date](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) or [chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration)), does the use high precision type of these libraries reduce performance(memory usage, speed) or is it independent of the type of precision?

high precision type:
nanoseconds, microseconds, milliseconds, ...

Comment: The only way I know to know for certain is to measure and find out.

Comment: From the `chrono` page: "The only data stored in a duration is a tick count of type Rep." The date library is not part of the standard, but I'd be surprised if it mattered. The source is on github. (The author is here sometimes and might provide the authoritative answer.) But if your program is dependent on the speed of date calculations, it could probably benefit from a redesign.

Comment: i have no measures but i'd say getting the system time will be constant with the division/multiplication when converting the resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of precision in a `chrono::duration` is a trade off between between precision and range, and has no impact on performance.

The chrono-supplied clocks each have a "native precision" documented by their nested `duration` type, and that is what it is (can not be changed by the client).  If you desire a `time_point` or `duration` different than that (after calling `now()`) the cost is a single multiplication or division to get your desired precision.  And once you have your desired precision, there is no further cost in using that precision.

The higher the precision, *generally* the smaller your range.  There is no over-flow protection unless you are using a custom `Rep` which supplies such checking.  You can check your range with static `duration::min()/max()` member functions.

A source of run-time error can come about in converting a courser duration with a very large but in-range value to a finer precision which results in overflow at the finer precision.  For example if you have more than 292 years worth of `microseconds` and convert that to `nanoseconds`, you will get overflow.